# Firebase Auth: Getting an AuthCredential after sign in using FirebaseUI-Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have an Android app with a few activities and a long-running service. The service has some model classes, POJOs that are stored in a Firebase Database.

On first run, the app determines that the the user hasn't logged in yet and uses FirebaseUI-Android to offer an account picker activity with Google and Facebook on it. This is pretty common:

```
    Intent signInIntent = AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setProviders(Arrays.asList(
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build(),
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build()))
            .setTheme(R.style.AppThemeFirebaseAuth)
            .setLogo(R.drawable.logo)
            .setIsSmartLockEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .build();

    activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, Request.FIREBASE_AUTH);
```

I can then get a `FirebaseUser` and start doing stuff with the database.

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

DatabaseReference firebaseUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
```

The problem arises on the next run of the service, which may be when no activity is around. I would like to do some database operations again, but without any user interaction. Looks like I need to call `FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential()`, but where do I get the `AuthCredential` reference? The `AuthCredential` is not passed back to the activity that starts sign in.

Can I use the Smart Lock stuff in FirebaseUI-Android to help here?

Comment: Cant you access FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); from your service? Since it is a static method you should be able to access it from anywhere.

Comment: Of course. Returns null.

Comment: @SaurabhPadwekar I spoke to soon, sorry! It appears this returns null much less often than I at first feared. I'll do some testing over the next few weeks and update this with my findings, but I may not have to persist an AuthCredential at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.
From this thread https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/123

> Ah, we have a slight problem here after discussing this with some colleagues. There is deliberately no way to get back an AuthCredential from an existing user, to avoid potentially leaking credentials. So, the linking of the authentication method to the anonymous account would have to occur within Firebase UI if you are using the library. I'll take a look at this next week to get you unblocked ASAP